# Sintax error at or near "Select"

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Estou tentando exibir o conteúdo do Banco de dados PostGresSql com a tabela chamada funcionário, usando os componentes Botton e BDGrid do delphi para exibir, eu inseri os comando assim:

```
untDMPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.Close;
untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.SQL.Add('Select * from funcionarios');
untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.Open;
```

Os dados são exibidos normalmente sempre que aperto o Botton, mas quando clico uma segunda vez no Botão "Exibir Dados" o Delphi informa um error:

> Sintax error at or near "Select"

Comment: o método Add deve estar sendo chamado a cada clique, fazendo com que a query fique `'Select * from funcionariosSelect * from funcionarios'` no segundo... e sucessivamente... você tem que adicionar apenas uma vez, ou limpar antes de adicionar a cada clique

Comment: Se você colocar um `;` no final do comando `SELECT` ele não dará erro mas irá repetir a exibição tantas vezes quantos forem os cliques.

Comment: Não tem como voce fazer assim: "untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.SQL.Text := 'Select * from funcionarios';"

Comment: Ai em vez de adicionar a string ele subscreve ela

Comment: Colocar o ; Resolveu

Answer (score 1):

Tente limpar o SQL da sua query antes..

```
Query.SQL.Clear;
```

Ou então ao invés de utilizar a função Add utilize o Text:

```
Query.SQL.Text := '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que o botão é clicando está sendo adicionada uma nova linha à query. Sql.Add não apaga o texto anterior, apenas adiciona o novo texto ao fim da Stringlist.

Coloque este código no OnClick do botão, clique duas ou mais vezes e veja como fica seu SQL:
`ShowMessage(untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.SQL.Text)`

O @GabrielLocalhost já deu a resposta:

`untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.SQL.Text := 'Select * from funcionarios'`

Answer (score 0):

O correto é você limpar a list antes de tentar adicionar uma nova consulta.
A propriedade `SQL` é provavelmente derivada de um `TList`, portanto, utilize o comando `Clear`.

```
untDMPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.Close;
untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.SQL.Clear;
untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.SQL.Add('Select * from funcionarios');
untDmPrincipal.DMPrincipal.UniQuery2.Open;
```

Colocar o ponto e vírgula NÃO RESOLVE o problema, apenas tampará o sol com a peneira. Desta forma estaria executando múltiplas consultas. Para o banco de dados vai chegar:

```
Select * from funcionarios;Select * from funcionarios;Select * from funcionarios....
```

ele vai entender e executara todas as consultas e você terá acesso apenas à última, porem, ficará transações abertas para cada cursor que ele utilizou.

Comment: Eu particularmente não gosto de usar essa forma, porque adiciona uma linha a mais no código, uma comando a mais para ser feito, prefiro não usar o Clear e Add, uso o Text que ele subscreve o sql